# Easier way to initialize multiple variables to the same value in a new object

Tags: c#

Is there an easier way to do the write the following code when the values are the same?

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass()
{
    var1 = someValue,
    var2 = someValue,
    var3 = someValue,
    var4 = someValue
}
```

Comment: assign the values in the constructor and pass the single value to the constructor

Comment: Why do you want multiple variables with same value. You can use single variable multiple times if assigned value is same. Instead of multiple variable.

Comment: What operations you want to do with all these variables. -1 for uncleared question. Kindly update your question which shows use of these variable. By looking into deep we can suggest some better design here

Answer (score 2):

Or, use this behavior:

```
The result of an assignment expression is the value assigned to the left-hand operand
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator

And assign the properties like this:

```
var c = new someClass();
c.var1 = c.var2 = c.var3 = c.var4 = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

This sets all four variables to the same value:

```
string var1, var2, var3, var4;

var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = "Hello World!";
```

All string variables contain "Hello World!" after execution.

Comment: @PontusVarg You may want to mark this response as an `Answer`, or if it did not work for you please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a constructor parameter in the class.

```
someClass()
{
    type var1, var2, var3, var4;

    someClass(type someValue)
    {
        var1 = someValue;
        var2 = someValue;
        var3 = someValue;
        var4 = someValue;
    }
}

someClass c = new someClass(somevalue);
```